# How can i retrieve a single column from a database using a different column defined by the user? CI/PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to retrieve a row from a database with codeigniter. I won't use real table names of my table but basically, say that X user is logged in and this username (X) is in the column 'username'. How can i then retrieve the data from the column called 'hello' for just this user?

Comment: `$this->db->select('hello')->where('id',$id)->limit(1)->get('user');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo $this->db->where('username', $userName)->get('tableName')->row()->hello;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have all this data in one table, and each user only has one row of data, you could do the following:

```
$data = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE username = 'x'");
$results = $data->row();
echo $results->hello;
```

If each user has more than one row of data, it can be achieved by the following:

```
$data = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE username = 'x'");
foreach($data->result() as $d) {
   echo $d->hello;
}
```

It should be noted that if more than one row is being returned, a new table structure should be considered to remove the risk of data duplication.